# Wordpress wp_nav_menu walker: dynamic before content

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I build a navigation within a wordpress blog. the items are displayed like this:

[image]

The icon is applied by using the bootstrap classes `glyhicon-glyphiconname`. I add the classes dynamically. The php code for that:

```
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
     // check if the item is in the primary menu
     if( $args->theme_location == 'directentries' ) {
       foreach($item as $key => $value) {
           if($key == 'title') {
             $catIcon = setCatIcon($value);
           }
       }
       // add the desired attributes:
       $atts['class'] = 'btn btn-primary btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-'.$catIcon;
     }
     return $atts;
 }
 add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );

$args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'directentries',
        'depth'      => 1,
        'container'  => false,
        'menu_class'     => 'nav',
        'link_before'  => '<br>', 
        //'link_before'  => 'span class"glyphicon"',
        'walker'     => ''
    );
    wp_nav_menu($args);
```

The problem here is, that the font of the link text is (of course) glyhicon, otherwise the icon would not apply to the link. So: The correct way would be to apply a **span** using the **link-before** parameter when initialising the menu. 
But I need to apply my dynamic classname to the **span** then. 
I think I could access the **link_before** param within my filter class using the $args parameter..

The current markup is this:
[image]
And I need it to be linke this:
[image]
Does anyone have an idea how to apply a span and vary the classes?

.

Comment: Please add ur navigation item markup

Comment: Of course. This is exactly why I upvoted your answer 1-2 days after you answered. And also I mentioned you in my answer. Which kind of additional action to show my gratitude do you consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a custom Nav Walker class might be a good (better?) solution as @Trix suggested, I want to answer the question how to apply a span using my filter. This code did it:

```
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
     if( $args->theme_location == 'directentries' ) {
       foreach($item as $key => $value) {
           if($key == 'title') {
             $catIcon = setCatIcon($value);
           }
       }
       foreach($args as $key => $value) {
           if($key == 'link_before') {
              $args->$key = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'.$catIcon.'"></span><br>';
           }
       }
       // add the desired attributes:
       $atts['class'] = 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'; 
     }
     return $atts;
 }
 add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Can somebody explain me the function setCatIcon(), I am using this code but it says setCatIcon undefined. Please help

Comment: Can somebody explain me the function setCatIcon(), I am using this code but it says setCatIcon undefined. Please help. Actually my requirement is to get the value of field "CSS Classes (optional)" instead "Navigation Label" value

Answer (score 2):

**1. Add code below to your functions.php first.**

```
class Nav_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
     function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

        if ( 'primary' == $args->theme_location ) {
            $submenus = 0 == $depth || 1 == $depth ? get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'value' => $item->ID, 'fields' => 'ids' ) ) ) ) : false;
            $item_output .= ! empty( $submenus ) ? '<span class="glyphicon"></span>' : '';
        }
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

**2. Add code below to your header.php where your wp_nav_menu  is installed.**

Explained below is the code so it installs the new custom menu in this case would be `Nav_Walker_Nav_Menu`.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'walker' => new Nav_Walker_Nav_Menu() ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok here is what I did and modified the answer to get the value of field "CSS Classes (optional)". Its more useful code because the current answer is fetching the value of "Navigation Label" field and sometime we need a dynamic custom class for icons.

How I did this-
converted the array into string and as we know the string will get all CSS classes, so used `strtok` function to get the first class from the string. When we add a custom class to field "CSS Classes (optional)", it always appears the first word in array.

```
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
     if( $args->theme_location == 'topcontact' ) {
       foreach($item as $key => $value) {
           if($key == 'classes') {
             $catIcon = implode(" ", $value);
           }
       }
       foreach($args as $key => $value) {
           if($key == 'link_before') {
              $args->$key = '<i class="fas fa-'.strtok($catIcon, " ").'"></i>';
           }
       }
       // add the desired attributes:
       $atts['class'] = ''; 
     }
     return $atts;
 }
 add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );
```